# Linking to an anchor within a div

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I am building a web-app for bible study and am running into issues trying to change the display/navigation. For reference, the site is www.jbtbible.com.

Currently, you can have 1 to 4 reading panes open, and each pane will display a single chapter of a given book, so selecting a given chapter or clicking the buttons to advance or reverse a chapter will load the appropriate html file into the given div and display that chapter. This needs to change to instead load the entire book into the div, and then selecting a chapter from the dropdown will simply link to that chapter within the loaded document (allowing scrolling between chapters of a single book instead of having to navigate between them).

The problem I'm running into with this though is that the same ids will appear in each loaded div (e.g. "chapter1", "chapter2", etc.). How do I control which div will link to the proper chapter without affecting any of the other loaded books/chapters in the other divs?

I also tried playing with this on a single pane version I built for mobile use and when I try to select a chapter from the dropdown it is trying to link out externally for some reason even though I'm pointing to href="#chapter1".

Comment: you should not have duplicate ids. if you have duplicates then they should be classes. An ID uniquely identifies an element.

Comment: so instead of just using the chapter number combine the panel number and chapter number like `panel1-chapter1`

Answer (score 1):

If the same ID is being re-used multiple times in the document, then that's invalid markup and the behavior will be undefined and browser-specific.  Since you're loading the same segments of the document into the DOM multiple times, I suggest switching the IDs to classes instead.

> it is trying to link out externally for some reason even though I'm pointing to href="chapter1"

That's because `href="chapter1"` is a link to an external resource named `chapter1`.  To link to an anchor within the current document, prepend it with a `#`:

```
href="#chapter1"
```

In this case, `chapter1` should be the `name` of the target anchor, not an `id` of a `div` or anything like that.  For example:

```
<a name="chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
```

More information about anchor tags is available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

Comment: The href="chapter1" was a mis-type on my part, I had it in as href="#chapter1". If I change to classes instead of ids though, is there still a way for me to link to that class? Or will I have to use jquery at that point?

Comment: @Belizzle: What do you mean by "link to that class"?  You don't link to classes or ids, you link to anchors and external resources (pages).  Can you include in your question the code you're using and explain what's not working?  Maybe provide a live example on something like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use classes rather than ids if they are duplicating on the same page.  You might want something like:

```
<div id="chapter1" class="chapter">
  <div class="readingpane" id="readingpane-chapter1"></div>
  <div class="navpane" id="navpane-chapter1"></div>
</div>

<div id="chapter2" class="chapter">
  <div class="readingpane" id="readingpane-chapter2"></div>
  <div class="navpane" id="navpane-chapter2"></div>
</div>
```

Then you might mainipulate them something like this

```
$('.navpane').click(function(){
  var currentReadingPane = $(this).closest('.chapter').find('.readingpane');
});
```

OR

```
$('.navpane').click(function(){
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  //....
});
```